# Removing malware between users

Tags: malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

When logging onto my computer which is infected with a vicious malware / virus that has disabled my user "side" of the computer I can log onto my wife's user name which is not disabled and have downloaded a virus removal program but it is not detecting the malware that has infected my user domain. How do I get the program to scan my user "side" of the computer?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on which antivirus you are using but to simplify this process download and run the MSS http://www.microsoft.com/security/scanner/en-us/default.aspx and run it. If you are not running MSE this will give you a second scanner as well to help remove it.

To get your current scanner to scan her files you should be able to go the Documents and Settings or Users folder in your OS drive and right click on her folder, you should find a scan option there.